# Reverse for '' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to implement a way to change some saved settings on my app , the user should be able to view and change these settings accordingly.

However , the above error is received when trying to load the "SettingsHome" page.

Please see the below code and full error message:

Error:

> NoReverseMatch at /settings Reverse for 'viewSettings' with arguments
> '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['accConnect/setting/(?P<settings_pk>[0-9]+)$'] Request Method:   GET
> Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/settings Django Version:  3.2
> Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch Exception Value:  Reverse for
> 'viewSettings' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['accConnect/setting/(?P<settings_pk>[0-9]+)$'] Exception
> Location: C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py,
> line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix Python
> Executable:   C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.9.4 Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\KylePOG\Documents\GMA Programming\accConnect',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages']
> Server time:  Tue, 14 Sep 2021 08:30:03 +0000 Error during template
> rendering In template C:\Users\KylePOG\Documents\GMA
> Programming\accConnect\main\templates\main\base.html, error at line 7
>
> Reverse for 'viewSettings' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1
> pattern(s) tried: ['accConnect/setting/(?P<settings_pk>[0-9]+)$']
> 1  2    3   4         5          /* The sidebar menu */ 6        .sidenav { 7
>
> height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
> 8         width: 160px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */ 9
>
> position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */ 10
>
> z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */ 11          top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
> 12            left: 0; 13         background-color: #111; /* Black */ 14
>
> overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */ 15
> padding-top: 20px; 16       } 17

**CODE**

Views.py:

```
def settingsHome(request):

    allClass = SettingsClass.objects.all().order_by('Complex')
    return render(request, 'main/settingsHome.html' , {'allClass' : allClass})

def viewSettings(request,  settings_pk):
    setting = get_object_or_404(SettingClass, pk=settings_pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = SettingForm(instance=setting)
        return render(request, 'meter_readings/viewSettings.html', {'setting': setting, 'form':form})
    else:
        try:
            form =  SettingForm(request.POST, instance=setting)
            form.save()
            return redirect('settingsHome')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'meter_readings/viewSettings.html', {'setting': setting, 'form':form, 'error':'Bad info'})
```

viewSettings.html:

```
{% extends "main/base.html"%}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">

{% block content %}

{{ error }}

 {{ setting.Complex }}

<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

settingHome.html:

```
{% extends "main/base.html"%}


{% block content %}
{% for entry in allClass %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mx-lg-n5">
    <a href="{% url 'viewSettings' settings.id %}">»  {{ entry.Complex }}</a>
  </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}

<br>

<a href="{% url 'newSetting' %}" class="btn btn-primary">➕ Add New Setting</a>

{% endblock %}
```

Urls.py:

```
#Settings
path('settings', views.settingsHome , name='settingsHome'),
path('ns' , views.newSetting , name='newSetting'),
path('accConnect/setting/<int:settings_pk>', views.viewSettings, name='viewSettings' ),
```

I think there is something wrong with the 'pk' implementation, but I just can't figure it out.

If anyone can see anything wrong in this code, please assist.

Comment: comment out this line in settinghome.html <a href="{% url 'viewSettings' settings.id %}">»  {{ entry.Complex }}</a>,  it has a pk that is not being passed to settingsHome view that renders settinghome.html template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem in your `settinghome.html`

```
 <a href="{% url 'viewSettings' settings.id %}">» {{ entry.Complex }}</a>,
```

The view that renders settinghome.html does not expect pk which you are calling on `ViewSetting` url.

**Update**

use `entry.id` instead of `settings.id`

```
{% for entry in allClass %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mx-lg-n5">
    <a href="{% url 'viewSettings' entry.id %}">»  {{ 
 entry.Complex }}</a> <!--replace setting.id with entry.id -->
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have removed that code , and it loads now. But I still need this to link to the 'viewSetting' page. How would I call the 'viewSetting' page properly in the href?

Comment: i have updated my answer, to include a possible solution